Set Action server-side grouping with AG-GRID react
I was able to retrieve the server-side group state using getServerSideGroupLevelState(), the issue is when grouping state expands, able to get grouping state on each expanded level, once collapse is done for a specific step and getServerSideGroupLevelState() is triggered, it does not remove the group level on the collapse , instead it render the all the grouping state including the collapsed one.
How to execute grouping collapse and expand right, can anyone suggest right way
Here is my code used to preserve grouping after refresh grid is triggered
// Function preserve group state
`const isServerSideGroupOpenByDefault = useCallback((params) => {
    let isValid = false;
    const groupLevels = // my array on group state
    if (groupLevels.length > 0) {
        for (const key in groupLevels) {
            if (!groupLevels[key]) {
                return false;
            }
            isValid = isValid || params.rowNode.key === groupLevels[key];
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}, []);
api.getServerSideGroupLevelState()` used to get grouping levels`

